# How to change unity launch application to wiggle?

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher, animations

Is there any easy way to use the wiggle animation (which is used to indicate urgent program) as the animation for launching application instead of the pulsing way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only choose between "*pulse*", "*blink*" and "*no animation*".